# how to add JS to django

Tags: javascript, html, django

i have a html form named "default.html" in "mysite\templates\admin" folder, and i have set the TEMPLATE_DIR in setting.py. Then i want to add a JS for the default.html, how can i do this?

For example, i put a JS file named "example.js" in "mysite_new\mysite\static\admin\js", what can i do to link the js file.

```
#defaul.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="xxxxx" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
          <legend>{{ Title_name }}</legend>
          <div>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="summary" checked="checked" />
                Name
              </label>
                      </div>
        </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need server your **example.js** as a static file from another server or setup static file serving using Django itself(check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)). I must say its not recommended to let django server static files

Comment: so how to let django server dynamic files? Can i use js file as the ways of {% static "admin/css/base.css" %}, if so, what should i config the paramater "static" in setting.py?

Comment: Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development to know how let django know about the static files. And yes you could use that code after setting up.

Comment: thanks, the last question, do you know the <img src="{% static "admin/img/icon_searchbox.png" %}  the "static" is defined in which place ?  This is the source code in django's templates form